# automapper map from non generic type to generic type

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, automapper, mapper

Is it possible (and how) to create map from non generic type to generic type?
Assuming we have:

```
public interface IFoo
{
     string Foo { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericFoo<TDestination> where TDestination : class
{
     string Baboon { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use open generics by doing so (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics):

```
CreateMap(typeof(IFoo), typeof(IGenericFoo<>)
```

but failed in runtime with the following error:

> {"The type or method has 1 generic parameter(s), but 0 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter."}

Automapper version: 4.2.1

Comment: What do you expect `TDestination` to be when you apply the mapping?

Comment: actually any class I will provide during Mapper.Map invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works for AutoMapper versions 5.x and higher. Here's a working example:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public class Source : IFoo
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination<T> : IGenericFoo<T> where T : class
    {
        public string Baboon { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IGenericFoo<TDestination> where TDestination : class
    {
        string Baboon { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create the mapping
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Source), typeof(Destination<>)));

        var source = new Source { Foo = "foo" };

        var dest = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination<object>>(source);

        Console.WriteLine(dest.Baboon);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpBp7k